# How to use Selenium Webdriver on Heroku?

Tags: node.js, selenium, heroku, webdriver, scraper

I am developing a Node.js app, and I use Selenium Webdriver on it for scraping purposes. However, when I deploy on Heroku, Selenium doesn't work. How can I make Selenium work on Heroku?

Comment: Hello man, have you found the solution for this? I'm also using Node on the server and using Angular on frontend, everything works locally but after I deployed it on heroku, selenium doesn't work

Comment: check my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60586343/11135757

Answer (score 8):

Below is a javaScript sample code using selenium-webdriver npm package with chrome browser.

```
const webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver');
const chrome = require('selenium-webdriver/chrome');

let options = new chrome.Options();
//Below arguments are critical for Heroku deployment
options.addArguments("--headless");
options.addArguments("--disable-gpu");
options.addArguments("--no-sandbox");

let driver = new webdriver.Builder()
  .forBrowser('chrome')
  .setChromeOptions(options)
  .build();

driver.get('http://www.google.com');
driver.quit();
```

Before you are ready to deploy, you would need to add two buildpacks to Heroku.

- Using Heroku buildpacks command:

```
$ heroku buildpacks:add --index 1 https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-chromedriver
$ heroku buildpacks:add --index 2 https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-google-chrome
```

or

- Config in Heroku dashboard:
  Settings -> Add buildpacks -> https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-chromedriver -> Save changes 
  Settings -> Add buildpacks -> https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-google-chrome -> Save changes

Comment: Hi folks, so with this setup is it possible to disable w3c mode?

Answer (score 4):

I was able to get the Selenium Webdriver working on Node/Heroku using PhantomJs as the headless browser. I installed the PhantomJs buildpack to my Heroku app and it just worked. I struggled to get Chrome and Firefox drivers working on Heroku... I wrote a blog with the steps and code I used to get it working:

http://www.viderman.com/2017/05/selenium-on-heroku.html

Comment: Please include the steps and code in your answer. Answers should not rely on external links for the majority of their information.

Comment: Same could be said about the blog post :)  External references have a way of being deleted.

Answer (score 0):

Pasting my answer from here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60586343/11135757

---

Note: I am using React, Express, and Selenium with chrome

Step 1: Create a new Heroku app.

Step 2: From your terminal, login to heroku using `heroku login`

step 3: Once you're logged in, `cd` to your project directory and set its remote to your heroku app. `heroku git:remote -a YOUR-HEROKU-APP-NAME`

step 4: Run all the following commands in your terminal

```
heroku buildpacks:add https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-chromedriver
heroku buildpacks:add https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-google-chrome
heroku config:set CHROME_DRIVER_PATH=/app/.chromedriver/bin/chromedriver
heroku config:set CHROME_BINARY_PATH=/app/.apt/opt/google/chrome/chrome
```

step 5: Login to heroku from your browser and navigate to your app. Go to settings and under `buildpacks`, add `heroku/nodejs`

step 6: This is how my index.js looks like. Note: my express entry point is inside `root-dir/server/index.js` and my react files are inside `root-dir/client/`

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const path = require('path');

// Serve static files from the React app. 
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '..', 'client/build')));


app.get('/api', async (req, res) => {
    const webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver');
    require('chromedriver');
    const chrome = require('selenium-webdriver/chrome');

    let options = new chrome.Options();
    options.setChromeBinaryPath(process.env.CHROME_BINARY_PATH);
    let serviceBuilder = new chrome.ServiceBuilder(process.env.CHROME_DRIVER_PATH);
    
    //Don't forget to add these for heroku
    options.addArguments("--headless");
    options.addArguments("--disable-gpu");
    options.addArguments("--no-sandbox");
  

    let driver = new webdriver.Builder()
        .forBrowser('chrome')
        .setChromeOptions(options)
        .setChromeService(serviceBuilder)
        .build();

    await driver.get('http://www.google.com');
    res.send(await driver.getTitle());
});

app.get('*', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '..', 'client/build/index.html'));
});

const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;
app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`listening to port ${port} now...`);
});
```

step 7 (if you are using React): Now inside your `package.json` in `root-dir/`, add this

```
"scripts": {
...
"heroku-postbuild": "cd client && npm install && npm run build"
}
```

step 8 (if you are using react): inside your `package.json` in `root-dir/client/` (i.e: `package.json` for react app), add the following line:

```
  "proxy": "http://localhost:5000/",
```

step 8: (if you're using react): inside `root-dir/client/src/`, create a new file called `setupProxy.js` and paste the following code:

```
const proxy = require("http-proxy-middleware");

module.exports = function(app) {
    app.use(proxy('/api', { target: `http://localhost:${process.env.PORT || 5000}/`}));
};
```

step 9: Now, you are ready for deployment. Make sure you have the following packages installed: `express`, `selenium-webdriver`, and `chromedriver`

step 10: now push it to heroku

```
git add .
git commit -m "my app"
git push heroku master
```