# How to setup Selenium on Heroku for Firefox?

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium, selenium-webdriver, heroku

I've made a node.js script like this:

```
const { Builder, By, Key, until } = require('selenium-webdriver');

const driver = new Builder().forBrowser("firefox").build();

const search_query = 'tigers';

(async () => {
    await driver.get(`https://www.google.com/search?q=${search_query}`);

    const h3Elements = await driver.findElements(By.css('h3'));
    for (const h3 of h3Elements) {
        console.log(await h3.getText());
    }

    console.log('...Task Complete!')
})();
```

and now I want to test it on a heroku server

but sadly I have no experience or understanding when it comes to setup

I tried following these link:
[How to use Selenium Webdriver on Heroku?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42860703/how-to-use-selenium-webdriver-on-heroku)
[How to run Selenium-Webdriver on Heroku with node.js (Firefox or Chrome)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58031466/how-to-run-selenium-webdriver-on-heroku-with-node-js-firefox-or-chrome)

but neither are for firefox
so how do I launch the above script on a heroku server? and what exactly is the process that is going on when it comes to web drivers on the server?

**EDIT**

I've added https://github.com/hamitaksln/heroku-integrated-firefox-geckodriver as a build pack

and set configuration  vars as such:

```
FIREFOX_BIN=/app/vendor/firefox/firefox

GECKODRIVER_PATH=/app/vendor/geckodriver/geckodriver

LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib:/usr/lib:/lib:/app/vendor

PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/app/vendor/
```

but it still shows an ERROR of incorrect path to geckodriver

Comment: Why would you test it on heroku? I ask, because both github and gitlab offer configurable CI, making the choice of heroku for this... unusual?

Comment: Get this to work in docker, set the heroku *stack* to `container` and deploy using docker on heroku

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans could you explain more of what you mean? I'm relatively new to web development I usually work on applications

Comment: @FalseDev could you provide the appropriate links for what you're saying?

Comment: @cakelover [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/categories/deploying-with-docker) it is